# Getting Specific Data from Post API in WordPress

Tags: json, wordpress

I want to link my website's Wordpress database to mobile application; and I am able to generate the APIs using wp-json plugin in Wordpress.

However, there is a lot of unwanted data which I do not want for the app. What are the custom parameters in the API url which will help me get only the information I am looking for?

http://www.indiafastener.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/2031

PS: I know I can manage & eliminate the unwanted information through the app as well however I do not want to unnecessarily pile up lot of data & do filters in the App.

Thanks for your time. 
Utpal

Answer (score 0):

Modern versions of WordPress have the REST API built into core therefore a plugin isn't required.

To check the arguments for an API call, take a look at the documentation. For retrieving a post, see: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#retrieve-a-post. There are no arguments for limiting the data provided by the response.

While it is possible to modify the response (https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/), I'd advise against it.

As you pointed out in your question, this data can be managed on the app side. I'd argue that is where you should be dealing with it. It's not about eliminating 'unwanted information' but rather recognising the information you do want.